# Python: display package choice from user

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure how to explain this very well, but I will do my best. 
I'm trying to display a sentence at the end to display the user choice of a package. However, the user only selects the package by a number.. for example

(sample output)
1. grapes $12
2. oranges $13
3. lemon $2

```
def load(packages)
    packageDict = {"name" : package, "cost": costPrice}
    packages.append(packageDict)


def calculate(packages)
    packageSelect  int(input("Select package"))
    while packageSelect > 5 or PackageSelect <1:
        print ("Invalid)
        packageSelect  int(input("Select package))

print("you have selected the"+ (package) + "package")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

```
def load(packages)
    packageDict = {"name" : package, "cost": costPrice}
    packages.append(packageDict)


def calculate(packages)
    packageSelect  int(input("Select package"))
    while packageSelect > len(packages) or PackageSelect < 1:
        print ("Invalid input, retry")
        packageSelect = int(input("Select package"))
    return packageSelect

packages = ['a', 'b', 'c']

package = calculate(packages)

print("you have selected the"+ packages[package - 1] + "package")
```